# Не могу разобраться с типами в reduce

Tags: java

Есть матрицы 3 на 3:

```
[0, 0, 1]   [0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0]   ...   ...   ...
```

Мне нужно пройтись по всем таким матрицам и определить матрицы, у которых сумма по строкам/столбцам/диагоналям совпадают. Решил делать через reduce:

```
List<Object[]> resolvedMatrices = matrices.stream().reduce((a, b) -> {
    Object temp = new Object();

    if(a[0][0] + a[0][1] + a[0][2] == b[0][0] + b[0][1] + b[0][2]) {
        temp = new Object[]{a, b};
    }

    return temp;
});
```

Но что-то фигня какая-то у меня получается:

> bad return type in lambda expression: Object cannot be converted to int[][];

Что я делаю не так?

**UPD:**

Изменил типы данных.

```
List<int[][]> resolvedMatrices = matrices.stream().reduce((a, b) -> {
    int[][] temp = {};

    if(a[0][0] + a[0][1] + a[0][2] == b[0][0] + b[0][1] + b[0][2]) {
        temp = new int[a][b]; // ??????
    }

    return temp;
});
```

Comment: вы возвращаете неверный тип данных

Comment: @RomanC ну это-то понятно, но я нигде не объявлял `int[][]`.

Comment: тогда условие if не должно работать

Comment: вы бы полностью выложили метод, а также метод , из которого вызываете и , что передаете... будет на много легче определить проблему

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович да зачем целый метод. Там важна только переменная matrices, которая объявлена вот так: `List<int[][]> matrices`

Comment: ага, вы только что писали, что int[][] не объявляли... а в коллекции List<int[][]> matrices по-вашему, что лежит

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? Напишите сначала без Streams API.

Answer (score 1):

если вы хотите, не выкладывая код, то могу подсказать, как написать, чтобы это просто скомпилировалось. устроит ли вас, понятия не имею...

```
Optional<int[][]> resolvedMatrices = matrices.stream().reduce((a, b) -> {
    int[][] temp=null;
    if (a[0][0] + a[0][1] + a[0][2] == b[0][0] + b[0][1] + b[0][2]) {

    }

    return temp;
});
```

код в условном блоке реализуйте по своему усмотрению

лучше напишите таким образом

```
private boolean arrayCalc (int[][] array){

    int sumArray [] = new int [array.length*2];
    boolean result = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            sumArray [i]+=array[i][j];
            sumArray [array.length+j]+=array[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
        if (sumArray[i]!=sumArray[i-1]) {
            result = false;
            break;
        } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Вот как раз с этим у меня и проблема. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, обновлённый вопрос. У меня теле условного оператора в `List<int[][]> resolvedMatrices` должно пушиться значение вроде `[[a], [b]]`. Но как так сделать, не изменяя тип на `Object[]{}`?

Comment: т.е. вы хотите в возвращаемое значение 2 массива засунуть или как?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Ну тогда нескромный вопрос... А кто вам посоветовал делать это через reduce? Идея reduce в том, чтобы преобразовать все элементы стрима в один объект. Например, посчитать сумму всех элементов, либо найти минимальный элемент. А вам нужен совсем не один объект. Вам нужна коллекция , состоящая из массивов, сумма значений которых повторяется. Хотите для решения этой задачи использовать стримы - я бы смотрел в сторону collect. Одна из самых мощных штук во всем streamAPI, при желании можно написать свой коллектор, реализовав интерфейс Collector.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю Вашу цель. Вы берете каждый элемент коллекции, там массив, в котором нужно посчитать сумму по всем строкам/столбцам/диагоналям. Если в итоге все значения совпали, то добавить массив в новую коллекцию? или вы еще хотите разные массивы между собой сравнивать?

Comment: В JavaScript есть функция `.reduce()`, которая, если на пальцах, сравнивает элементы массива каждый-с-каждым. Здесь та же логика. Нужно найти все массивы, в которых сумма чисел совпадает по строкам/столбцам/диагоналям и записать их куда-то. Ну или просто вывести в консоль.

Comment: так вы не на джаваскрипте сейчас пишите. к тому же вам не надо сравнивать все элементы массива, вам вообще их сравнивать не надо. вам надо считать суммы определенных элементом, а уже потом сравнивать суммы. я бы на вашем месте написал для этого отдельный метод, который будет проводить подобные операции с любыми массивами, не только 3х3 и просто вернет boolean. просто вам нужно вычислить 8 сумм для достижения цели и их сравнить. многовато будет, потом этот стрим прочитать нереально

Comment: Дописал метод, который считает суммы строк и колонок любых массивов, а потом их сравнивает, возвращает, соответственно, boolean. диагонали не считает, потому как не во всех массивах бывают диагонали. в любом случае вы это можете легко дописать, добавив в метод одно условие, проверяющее размер массива, как следствие. возможность посчитать диагонали. условие ставите перед оператором возврата. в этом случае, у вас еще есть переменная  result, котортая будет true только в том, случае, если все строки равны. если так, то сравнивайте результатирующий массив с диагоналями, а нет - сразу верните false